# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' in winform

Tags: winforms

I have project that I click Button and it's will create a new PictureBox (pb) on a PictureBox1. And when I choose item on a combobox and PictureBox (pb) will appear in the position I want and the problem appears. How can I fix it or use "pb" in void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged. Thank you.

```
private void btaddagv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewPictureBox();
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox AddNewPictureBox()
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pb);
        pb.Name = "STT" + tbAdd.Text;
        pb.Image = Image.FromFile("AGV-1.jpg");
        pb.Height = 30;
        pb.Width = 40;
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(tdx, 500);
        tdx = tdx + 200;
       return pb;
    } 
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox3.SelectedItem == "A")
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.Location = lbA.Location;
        }
    }
```

[And here is an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3AE8.png)

Comment: `(PictureBox)sender` ← the sender of the event is `comboBox3`.

Comment: how can i use "pb" in void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: When you add them, either in the Click handler or AddNewPictureBox, keep track of them in a List or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we make an assumption on this line:

```
pb.Name = "STT" + tbAdd.Text;
```

that tbAdd.Text contains the A, B, C, D etc that you're checking for here:

```
if(comboBox3.SelectedItem == "A")
```

Then your SelectedIndexChanged event handler should be:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selected = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(selected))
    {
        PictureBox pb = picturebox1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Where(p => p.Name == $"STT{selected}").FirstOrDefault();
        if (pb != null)
        {
            Label lb = picturebox1.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Name == $"lb{selected}").FirstOrDefault();
            if (lb != null)
                pb.Location = lb.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

I've made some extra assumptions here. First I've assumed that the "lbA" control you're referring to is a Label. The second assumption is that lbA and the other controls are all share the same parent (picturebox1)

What the above is doing is getting the value of the SelectedItem (if we use your example with the letter A) then attempts to find any PictureBox controls that have the name STTA. If it finds one it looks for a Label on the same parent called lbA. If that exists then it moves the picturebox control to the location of the label.